# Phoenix/Ecto - query for matches in array of strings

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In one of my Phoenix app's tables, I have a field that is an array of strings. I would like to be able to use a `where: like()` type of query to see if any of the values in the array contain a query string - however, I'm not sure how to do that. In a previous iteration of the app, the field in question was just a string field, and the following query worked perfectly:

```
results = from(u in User,
    where: like(u.fulltext, ^("%#{search_string}%"))
    |> Repo.all()
```

Now that I have changed the `fulltext` field into an array of strings (`character varying(255)[]`, in Postgres terms), this query understandably fails with the error

```
ERROR 42883 (undefined_function): operator does not exist: character varying[] ~~ unknown
```

but I'm not sure how I might refine the query to match the new schema.

For example, a user's `fulltext` field will look like

```
["john smith", "john@test.com"]
```

and the associated record should be returned when `search_string` is `"john"` or `"@test"` or `"n smith"`, etc. - if the `search_string` matches any part of either of the list values.

In plain English, the query would read something like "return records where a value like `search_string` is found in the list `u.fulltext`".

I can think of various 'hacky' workarounds, like just returning the list of all users and then using some chained `Enum.map` functions to run through them and check the values of `fulltext` for partial matches, but if there's a more elegant solution using Ecto's query syntax, I would much rather opt for that. Can anyone offer any guidance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `unnest` in PostgreSQL with a subquery to check if any item of an array is `LIKE something`:

```
from(p in Post, select: p.tags, where: fragment("exists (select * from unnest(?) tag where tag like ?)", p.tags, "%o%")
```

In your case, this should work:

```
from(u in User, where: fragment("exists (select * from unnest(?) tag where tag like ?)", u.fulltext, ^("%#{search_string}%"))
```

```
iex(1)> Repo.insert! %Post{tags: ~w(foo bar baz)}                                                                              [debug] QUERY OK db=0.3ms
iex(2)> Repo.insert! %Post{tags: ~w(quux)}
iex(3)> Repo.insert! %Post{tags: ~w(hello world)}
iex(4)> query = "%o%"
"%o%"
iex(5)> Repo.all from(p in Post, select: p.tags, where: fragment("exists (select * from unnest(?) tag where tag like ?)", p.tags, "%o%"))
[debug] QUERY OK source="posts" db=3.9ms
SELECT p0."tags" FROM "posts" AS p0 WHERE (exists (select * from unnest(p0."tags") tag where tag like '%o%')) []
[["foo", "bar", "baz"], ["hello", "world"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `fragment` and `unnest` to convert the array to a join:

```
user_texts = 
  from u in User, 
  select: %{id: u.id, fulltext: fragment("unnest(fulltext)")}

query = 
  from u in User, 
  join: t in subquery(user_texts), on: u.id == t.id, 
  where: like(t.fulltext, ^("%#{search_string}%")), 
  select: u,
  distinct: true

Repo.all(query)
```

Comment: Hey, could you please add example if fulltax is aray of maps ?

Comment: @DokiCRO could you please ask as a new question with an example of the schema?